# How to correctly define a WooCommerce variable in Wordpress functions.php?

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, woocommerce

I have the following code, which works as intended, but I also get an error report about "Undefined variable: checkoutfee". Why is it not defined correctly below?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_checkout_fee' );
  
function add_checkout_fee() {
   foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        if ( isset( $cart_item['checkout-fee'] ) ) {
            $checkoutfee = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if ( $checkoutfee == true ) WC()->cart->add_fee( __( 'Fee', 'wpml-text-domain' ), 0 );
}
```

thank you in advance for any tips

Comment: Just put this line before the foreach loop `$checkoutfee = false;`, 
it will solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

It's a PHP error. you are using a variable that was never defined.
it's easy. just use a predefined:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_checkout_fee' );
function add_checkout_fee() {
   $checkoutfee == ''; //Added this line

   foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        if ( isset( $cart_item['checkout-fee'] ) ) {
            $checkoutfee = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if ( $checkoutfee == true ) WC()->cart->add_fee( __( 'Fee', 'wpml-text-domain' ), 0 );
}
```